# How can I determine the generic types used for a class in C#?

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to create a signal system in C#, with type-safe signals and delegates that are all validated at code-time. I'm trying to accomplish three things with my system, in priority order:

1. **Type safety** - Developers must not be able to send incorrect parameter types or pass functions with different signatures to a signal listener of a pre-defined signal type.
2. **Simple Syntax** - Creating new signals, registering/unregistering listeners, and calling signals needs to be quick, simple, and painless.
3. **Descriptive parameters** - When a developer calls a signal, the parameters required have names that reflect the usage of that parameter for this particular signal. e.g. `(string name, int age)` instead of `(string param1, int param2)`

I've accomplished points 1 and 2 with moderate success, and I don't think I'll be able to achieve point 3.

My current implementation uses a static parent class to send, register, and validate signals and their corresponding listener delegates. It works well, but I'm not thrilled with the syntax. This is what I have:

**Signal base class** (duplicated for each generic type count required ie, there is a SigClass<T,U>, SigClass<T,U,V> etc.):

```cs
public delegate void Callback<T>(T arg1);

public class SigClass<T>
{
    protected static Dictionary<string,Delegate> _event = new Dictionary<string, Delegate>();
    
    public static void Send<C>(T p1) where C : SCSigBase
    {
        string s = typeof(C).Name;
        if (!_event.ContainsKey(s)) { _event.Add(s, null);}
        Callback<T> callback = _event[s] as Callback<T>;
        callback?.Invoke(p1);
    }
    
    public static void Register<C>(Callback<T> function) where C : SCSigBase
    {
        string s = typeof(C).Name;
        if (!_event.ContainsKey(s)) { _event.Add(s, null);}
        
        _event[s] = (Callback<T>)_event[s] + function;
    }
    
    public static void Unregister<C>(Callback<T> function) where C : SCSigBase
    {
        string s = typeof(C).Name;
        if (!_event.ContainsKey(s)) { _event.Add(s, null);}
        
        _event[s] = (Callback<T>)_event[s] - function;
    }
}
```

**Declaring a new signal type:**

```cs
public class FooSig : SigClass<string> {}
```

**Registering/unregistering listeners, invoking signals:**

```cs
public void RunTests()
{     
    FooSig.Register<FooSig>(Bar);
    FooSig.Send<FooSig>("Hello, world!");
    FooSig.Unregister<FooSig>(Bar);
    FooSig.Send<FooSig>("You should not see this.");
}

public void Bar(string message) 
{
    Console.Write(message);
}
```

The template type `<C>` I send is exclusively to avoid collision with two signals with identical template parameters. It is redundant, and I'd like to improve it.

I want to try simplifying the signal calls from `RunTests()` to look something like this:

```cs
public void RunTests()
{
    SignalManager.Register<FooSig>(Bar);
    SignalManager.Send<FooSig>(Bar);
    SignalManager.Unregister<Foosig>(Bar);
    SignalManager.Send<FooSig>("You should not see this.");
}
```

That is, instead of an inherited class holding the Send/Register/Unregister signals with a static dictionary (in my first case, FooSig), I'd make a static class `SignalManager` where you can pass a SigType<T> in and have everything validate similarly.

**Here is my question:**

Is there a way to determine the generic types of a class used in its declaration, and use those to validate delegates that I will send?

In other words, if I declare `FooSig : SigClass<string>{}`, is there a way to pass along that declared generic type when checking the signatures of delegates?

I want this behavior:

```cs
public class FooSig : SigClass<string>{}

public void RunTests()
{
    SignalManager.Register<FooSig>(Bar);
    SignalManager.Register<FooSig>(Baz); // this should not compile, Baz's signature does  
                                         // not match FooSig's template type.

    SignalManager.Send<FooSig>("Hello, world!");
    SignalManager.Send<FooSig>(); // This should not compile, a string parameter is required
                                  // based on FooSig's template type.
}

public void Bar(string param)
{
    // do something
}

public void Baz(int param)
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: No, this is not possible, at least not statically. Some provisions could be made for `.Register` (`.Register(new FooSig(Bar))` could be made to work) but `SignalManager.Send<T>(...)` is clearly impossible as it would require a theoretically infinite number of overloads, one for each possible signature, and that's before any type checking of the arguments. Even if we ignore this little niggle, there is no way to statically declare that a class should be able to accept delegates of any type and at the same time have this verified at compile time; C# generics are not templates.

Comment: I suspected as much. I was holding out hope for some dark corner of C# with reflection data or something that kept track of the type of generic assigned to a generic class.

Comment: Well, using reflection you *can* get at all the information you want no problem -- `Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition`, `Type.GetGenericArguments`, `MethodInfo.GetGenericArguments`. The big problem there is that you can't use this information *statically*, so you can't have a method validating the arguments at compile time. You can certainly have one that validates and/or constructs the arguments at runtime.

Comment: Neat. That's great to know. You're right, it won't be useful here, but any time I wonder if I can do something weird, "reflection data" tends to be the answer.